# Bash: 'echo' not outputting variable defined on same line

Tags: bash, variables

This `echo` call outputs the variable:

```
$ FOO="bar" eval 'echo foo: "$FOO"'
foo: bar
```

But this one does not:

```
$ FOO="bar" echo foo: "$FOO"
foo:
```

Why is that? I'm pretty sure I have the single and double quotes right.

Environment-wise, I'm on a MacBook Pro using iTerm2 with a current version of `bash`:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.23(1)-release
```

Comment: See [Bash Reference Manual: Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion). Without a semi-colon, you are executing `echo` with `$FOO` added to its environment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is happening because in your second example, `$FOO` is being expanded before the line is evaluated.

EDIT:  This works if the second part is in a separate script:

```
$ cat foo.sh
echo foo: "$FOO"

$ FOO="bar" ./foo.sh
foo: bar
```

Or:

```
FOO="bar" bash -c 'echo $FOO'
```

Having the command in single quotes means it isn't expanded first by the shell.